# Enviar información a servicio por json

Tags: android, json, asynctask

Hola tengo un problema con el envió de información a un servicio ocupo okHttp al momento de enviarlo con fechas y horas me manda un error 
[image: Este es el error al momento de querer enviar la información con las horas y fechas si le quito los campos de horas y fechas el servicio me contesta con un 200]

mi código de como estoy mandando toda la información es el siguiente

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
                Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("WSUser", "Tums4.WS".toCharArray());
                    }
                });


 String json = "{\n" +
                        "  \"Equipo\": {\n" +
                        "    \"EquipoMotriz\": "+TrenMotriz+",\n" +
                        "    \"Viajes\": {\n" +
                        "      \"NoViaje\": "+NoViaje+",\n" +
                        "      \"Repartos\": {\n" +
                        "        \"Reparto\": {\n" +
                        "          \"Pedido\": "+ NumeroReparto +",\n" +
                        "          \"CartaPorte\": "+CartaPortePref+",\n" +
                        "          \"CargaFecIniR\": "+IcargaFecha+",\n" +
                        "          \"CargaHorIniR\": "+IcargaHora+",\n" +
                        "          \"CargaFecFinR\": "+FcargaFecha+",\n" +
                        "          \"CargaHorFinR\": "+FcargaHora+",\n" +
                        "          \"DescFecIniR\": "+FdescargaFecha+",\n" +
                        "          \"DescHorIniR\": "+FdescargaHora+",\n" +
                        "          \"DescFecFinR\": "+SdescargaFecha+",\n" +
                        "          \"DescHorFinR\": "+SdescargaHora+",\n" +
                        "          \"LlegaCteFecR\": "+CclienteFecha+",\n" +
                        "          \"LlegaCteHorR\": "+CclienteHora+",\n" +
                        "          \"SalidCteFecR\": "+SclienteFecha+",\n" +
                        "          \"SalidCteHorR\": "+SclienteHora+",\n" +
                        "          \"LlegaCteDesFecR\": "+CdescargaFecha+",\n" +
                        "          \"LlegaCteDesHorR\": "+CdescargaHora+",\n" +
                        "          \"SalidCteDesFecR\": "+SdescargaFecha+",\n" +
                        "          \"SalidCteDesHorR\": "+SdescargaHora+",\n" +
                        "          \"Paradas\": {\n" +
                        "            \"Parada\": {\n" +
                        "              \"NUM_VIAJE\": "+NoViaje+",\n" +
                        "              \"PEDIDO\": \"test\",\n" +
                        "              \"ENTREGA\": \"test\",\n" +
                        "              \"CVE_PAR\": \"test\",\n" +
                        "              \"CLA_PAR\": \"test\",\n" +
                        "              \"TIP_PAR\": \"test\",\n" +
                        "              \"LATITUD\": \"test\",\n" +
                        "              \"LONGITUD\": \"test\",\n" +
                        "              \"FECHA_C\": \"test\",\n" +
                        "              \"HORA_C\": \"test\"\n" +
                        "            }\n" +
                        "          }\n" +
                        "        }\n" +
                        "      }\n" +
                        "    }\n" +
                        "  }\n" +
                        "}";



                DataOutputStream printout = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                printout.writeBytes(json);
                printout.flush();
                printout.close();
                Log.d(TAG, "LogWhileRequest:"+json);

                urlConnection.connect();
                StringBuffer response = null;
                int responseCodeConnection = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                if (responseCodeConnection == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    // Response
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    String inputLine;
                    response = new StringBuffer();
                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "LogWhileRequest:"+inputLine);
                        response.append(inputLine);

                    }
                    in.close();

                }
                assert response != null;
                return response.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Lo revise con postman y al mandar la misma información y estructura me contesta con el 200 éxito
[image: Este es el postman con la misma informacion y estructura]

Si me prodrian ayudar se los agradeceré muchísimo

Comment: has probado a cambiarle el formato de fecha por ejemplo "2015-02-15".

Comment: ya pero me sigue mandando el mismo error

Comment: Imprime algo esta linea en tu aplicación Log.d(TAG, "LogWhileRequest:"+inputLine); ?